# Can anyone identify this fake chinese tesla mobile connector?

Tags: adapter, power-connector

I got this from China as Tesla mobile connector adapter, but it does not fit a little bit wider and slimer. Below is the connector compare with tesla gen 2 connector(Chinese on top and Tesla's on the bottom).

[image]

Comment: Does it match gen 1?

Comment: I don't think so, i think gen 1 comes with soldered connector and only end plug is interchangeable.

Comment: Well it does not match gen2 so return it for a refund.

Comment: That probsbly fits Chinese teslas just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it mates with a European Tesla charger as seen in [this](https://www.greencarreports.com/news/1112348_how-teslas-charge-in-us-and-uk-similarities-and-differences) video around 1:40

[image]

Comment: No, EU Gen 1 connector looks like this: https://uploads.tff-forum.de/original/3X/a/8/a8c09f7bf7cad2d65889c66039c7f219d8c67d7d.jpeg